# Can you play after the main quest is done

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I'm about to complete the main quest but I don't want to be unable to finish all the sub-quests.

Am I going to be allowed to play after the main quest is done or should I finish everything before doing the last quest ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll still be able to roam and play the sub-quests after finishing the main quest.